# Access model from another controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, models, controllers

We have a small mvc we have built, we want to access models from different controllers.

i.e

```
class Controller {
    function A() {
    }
}

class Search extends Controller {
    function B() {
        $this->model->doSomething();    
    }
}

class Profile extends Controller {
    function B() {
        ***** HERE ***** ?????????????????????????????????????????????
        Search::doSomething();
    }
}

class Model {

}

class search_model extends Model {     
    public function doSomething() {
        // Do Something
        echo "doing something";
    }
}

class profile_model extends Model { 
    public function getProfile() {
        // Get Profile
        echo "getting profile";
    }
}
```

I want to access when in the Profile Controller the Search Controller function doSomething() if you can see like the  HERE  section or something along them lines?

Comment: Model is not a single instance but a layer.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the model in the other controller.
THere is nothing wrong with acessing the same model from several controllers

Comment: simply? require "models/search_model";

Comment: Or autoload, ultimatelly you will have this file acessible.

Answer (score 0):

Controller is the parent class of both Search and Profile, so you can add a function you can re-use for both.

```
class Controller {

    public $model;

    public function doSomething() {
        if($this->model === null)
        {
            $this->model = new search_model();
        }
        return $this->model->doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am wanting to access a function from the Model class?

Comment: You'd be better off with dependency injection for increased testability and usability. Furthermore, the model is not a class, it's a layer